# Launching activity on condition for loginactivity

Tags: android

I want to launch activity after login on 2 condition if user is active in Database entry i want to launch MainActivity.java if user is not active it should launch mobile verification screen i am using volley to make http calls and getting data from server here is my script

LoginActivity.java

```
// Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String phone = user.getString("phone");
                    String status = user.getString("status");


                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid,phone);
                    if(new String(status).equals("active") ) {
                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else{

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: i  am using this but not working if(new String(string).equals("active") ) {

Comment: There is nothing like that in your posted code.

Comment: pls check now i edited it

Comment: can you post the userobject json string ?

Comment: its okay now now its working i made a small mistake but thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are comparing two strings in a wrong way. You should edit

```
if(new String(status).equals("active") )
```

to:

```
if(status.contentEquals("active"))
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

```
                JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                String name = user.getString("name");
                String email = user.getString("email");
                String phone = user.getString("phone");
                String status = user.getString("status");


                // Inserting row in users table
                db.addUser(name, email, uid,phone);
                if(new String(status).equals("active") ) {
                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else{

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Verifyotp.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
```